# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProvider

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at pojo.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:33)
at business.Operator.main(Operator.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
```

[My config file link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17922522/)

Can anybody tell me why and how to solve?

Comment: You are missing library, i think hibernate-commons-annotations.jar

Comment: Include relevant code within the question rather than linking to an outside resource.